# What is the behavior of SET_DELEGATE in particular cases

Tags: michelson, baker, delegating

The [Michelson Documentation](https://tezos.gitlab.io/whitedoc/michelson.html) does not say much about this function:

```
SET_DELEGATE: Forge a delegation.
:: option key_hash : 'S   ->   operation : 'S
```

This left me wondering about its behavior and if can produce an error in any certain cases.

1. I am assuming `SET_DELEGATE` on `NONE` removes the delegationn and `SOME key_hash` sets the key_hash as the delegate, is this correct?
2. Will it produce an error if the `key_hash` is not a baker or if it was once a baker and no longer is?
3. Will it produce an error if the baker at the `key_hash` is fully delegated to?
4. Are there any other conditions in which `SET_DELEGATE` can produce an error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. That's correct - this constructs an operation, much the same as when you use client to `set delegate for ...` or `withdraw delegate from ...`.
2. If the `key_hash` is not a baker, it will produce "Unregistered delegate" error (unless it's self-delegation to register a new baker or to activate a inactive baker). It is currently not possible to de-register a baker.
3. If it's already delegated to the same baker, it will lead to "Unchanged delegated" error.
4. - Trying to de-register baker with `SET_DELEGATE NONE` leads to "Forbidden delegate deletion"
   - Trying to change delegate of a register baker also leads to "Forbidden delegate deletion"
   - Trying to re-activate an already active baker leads to "Delegate already active"
   - Trying to register a baker on account with 0 balance leads to "Empty delegate account"